# Searching an index for a value in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, try-except

```
    def time_constant_values(time_value, df, band_list):
        try:
            time_value in df.index
        except KeyError:
            print('The time value does not exist!')
        else:
            constants = []
            for band in band_list:
                constants.append(df.loc[time_value][band])
            t0_dict = dict(zip(band_list, constants))
            return t0_dict
```

The pandas dataframe contains time values in it's index formatted as hh:mm:ss. What am I doing wrong in the try except part?

I am trying to access the specific time row for certain colummns and then forming a dictionary with column labels as keys and the data values as values.

THANKS!!

Comment: I see a lot of things here, first what are you trying to do in your try block, and there is an else statement without an if.

Comment: @bhansa The else part is okay (valid python syntax), there are other issues...

Comment: Please accept an answer if you found it useful, and stick to one answer please. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The non-existence of a key does not throw a `KeyError`. It simply returns `False`. The `else` is always run, and you'll have issues when indexing on a non-existent key then. Try using an `if`:

```
def time_constant_values(df, time_value, band_list):
    if time_value in df.index:
        return df.loc[time_value, band_list].to_dict()
```

Comment: When I try calling the function with your code, I get "KeyError: '10:28:00'" even though I know that is a value in the index. Does it make a difference that my index values are timedelta objects? @COLDSPEED

Comment: @Brain_overflowed it should not. I hope your code is exactly as portrayed in my answer. If yes, try converting `time_value` to timedelta as well.